# How to get owner of upstream build in downstream build without using parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have upstream and downstream pipelines and in downstream pipeline, I want to store user, who started upstream build, in downstream build variable.

I used following in downstream pipeline but it results into error - `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getUserId() on null object`

```
Owner = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause).getUserId()
```

One way is to store it in a variable in upstream pipeline and pass it as param to downstream pipeline but that is additional handling and considering my parameters list, it is little tricky.

Is there any way I can get user who started upstream build in downstream build without passing parameter?

Similarly, `JOB_NAME` and `BUILD_NUMBER` of upstream to downstream.

Comment: `currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause)` won't work as current build was not started by user; it was started by upstream build. You may want to use `currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause)` and examine the result of that.

Comment: Job A was triggered as a downstream project by Job B. And you want the Job_Name and Build_Number of Job that triggered this Job A along with the UserID of the one who triggered Job B. Right @TDHM ?

Comment: Yes @vijay, that is correct.

Comment: @MaratC, you solution did not work. It simply failed without giving any exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Your current build would print the below as the build cause when triggered by a user.**

`env.current_BUILD_CAUSE = currentBuild.getBuildCauses().toString()`

**env.current_BUILD_CAUSE:**

```
[
  {
    "_class": "hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause",
    "shortDescription": "Started by upstream project \"ABC/XYZ/JobA\" build number 621",
    "upstreamBuild": 621,
    "upstreamProject": "ABC/XYZ/JobA",
    "upstreamUrl": "job/ABC/job/XYZ/job/JobA/"
  }
]
```

**So now I'd take the necessary parameters from the above values. I'm not much familiar with the groovy way of doing it. So have used the `sh` directive.**

```
env.upstream_BUILD_NUMBER = sh(script: 'echo \"${current_BUILD_CAUSE}\" | jq .[].upstreamBuild | tr -d \'"\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
env.upstream_JOB_NAME = sh(script: 'echo \"${current_BUILD_CAUSE}\" | jq .[].upstreamProject | tr -d \'"\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
env.upstream_JOB_URL = sh(script: 'echo \"${current_BUILD_CAUSE}\" | jq .[].upstreamUrl | tr -d \'"\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
```

**Since, you don't want to pass parameters from one to another, I'd just curl the JSON api of the build and then use the same to get the values as required from upstream build. I'm using the credentials here since you may or may not need to authenticate to jenkins as per your requirement. You can remove that if not required along with -u arguments in curl.**

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'your-CredentialsID-for-Jenkins', usernameVariable: 'user', passwordVariable: 'password')]) {
  env.upstream_OWNER_ID = sh(script: "curl -s -u $user:$password https://${JENKINS_DASHBOARD}/${upstream_JOB_URL}/{upstream_BUILD_NUMBER}/api/json | jq -r \'.actions[].causes[]?.userId | select(length>0)\'", returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

**Now I'll have everything that is needed from both current and upstream build causes without passing any parameters from or to.**

***Note**: The code samples above also contains the escape sequences which I'm currently using in my jenkins job.*

Comment: In addition to what I've suggested, you can have conditions to check if the upstream project cause and then check to get the userId instead of directly looking for one.  it's just about adding 3 more lines of code to validate from the curl api response.

Comment: Why convert to JSON and then extract values from that using sh and jq, if you can just navigate the causes list directly?